# Slideshow with images and videos on a schedule

Tags: kiosk

I'm building a display/kiosk for a nightclub and would like a slideshow of images and videos that can be scheduled.
For example: On a Friday night, a slide show of a selection of images / video is displayed until 10pm, then at 10pm the selection of media changes, then again at midnight a new selection of media is shown.
Then on Saturday, a completely different selection of media, again at different times.

Is there software available for raspberry pi that can accomplish this - free, open source preferred, but will gladly pay for the right solution too.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: You'll want to have a look at digital signage solutions. There are several (free & paid) that run on a Pi. e.g. PiPresents. No idea if it can do all that you want though.

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/